# How to unit Test on aspx.cs

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to do a unit test on an aspx partial class, for example a `button_click` event.

I think this task is more suitable for an integration testing using "seleniumhq" or "watin".

The other way that I can think of doing this test is to extract the business logic from within this `eventHandler`, put it into a different class and perform unit test on that.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're moving in the right direction. Do some googling on "Model-View-Presenter" and "Passive View".

The idea is to move all logic from a code-behind file into a Presenter class that is an easily-instantiated and not platform dependent POCO. That presenter will be easily testable then. The code-behind code will be pretty "dummy", as the name "passive view" suggests.

EDIT: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318066/456181) is an example for WinForms but the pattern works for ASP.Net and even for Android Java as well.